# Why should I care about the highly radioactive elements after fermium?

Tags: elements, radioactivity

After element 100, fermium, there are a bunch of highly radioactive elements like fermium, tennessine, and oganesson, and others. These elements are to radioactive to store, they will instantly disappear, so we cannot use them in any way. If they are to radioactive to use, why should I care about them? I by NO means am saying that we should not care about them, I am asking what kind of potential they have?

Comment: Because science! Just because something doesn't appear to immediately have a use does not mean it's useless - in the context of what you are asking, have a look at the so-called [Island of Stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability).

Comment: The potential might not be apparent. The history of science is rife with discoveries that in turn led to other discoveries that changed things profoundly. Maybe the quest for stable elements in or around the island of stability leads to an efficient fuel source for satellites in the future. Or better medical treatments.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt I hope a use is discovered.

Comment: Thank goodness you didn't think about astronomy. I wonder what applications would you want from discovery of a galaxy 10 billion light-years away... Science is primarily about improving our knowledge and by detecting unknown elements we do just that. What can be done with knowledge is secondary thing.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt I am not saying we should not, I am asking if there are any possible applications for them

Comment: It's still a matter of opinion, in my opinion. Also, the question would probably be closed as too broad. You might reword it and try to get it reopened.